# Unable to lazy load images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to get my images to lazy load with JavaScript. For some reason, the images just do not show up at all when I change the html from src to data-src. Then when I use an intersectionObserver to lazy load images, I can't get any images to show up on the page. Attached is my html, css and JS code;

```
html:
<div class="photo__container photo__container--one">
        <img
          data-src="portrait/1-vertical.jpeg"
          alt=""
          class="fade-in-img img-vertical-lazy"
        />
        <img
          data-src="portrait/2-vertical.jpeg"
          alt=""
          class="fade-in-img img-vertical-lazy"
        />
        <img
          data-src="portrait/3-vertical.jpeg"
          alt=""
          class="fade-in-img img-vertical-lazy"
        />
      </div>

CSS:
.img-vertical-lazy {
  height: 70rem;
  width: auto;
}

JS:
const lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll('.img-vertical-lazy');


const appearLazy = {
  threshold: 0.1
};
const lazyLoading = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;
          entry.target.src = entry.target.getAttribute('data-src');
          lazyLoading.unobserve(entry.target);
  });
}, appearLazy);

lazyImages.forEach(image => lazyLoading.observe(image));
```

Comment: You can use the native `loading=lazy` on the images instead of all the JavaScript and the intersection observer :]

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum `loading=lazy` only has support on 74% of clients currently: https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr

Comment: I can't ever get this feature to work for me. Everytime I add this to the image and check the network for when it loads, it always loads instantly. This is why I am using an intersection observer @Ben

Comment: Your code works for me. The `src` is correct? https://jsfiddle.net/8bxd5spn/

Comment: Yes. If I change the html to just src then the images will appear. But when I make the images a data-src they disappear and don't show up even though the entire section containing the images is in the viewport. @azeós

Comment: Is there more code you could share? I don't see any problem there.

Comment: The code should work it's strange. I am using a package.json script that uses parcel to create a live-server. Everytime I assign a data-src to the html the images just completely disappear on every page of my website. Even when I console.log the entry.target it says the src is the correct file except the image won't show up (yes the path to the image is correct) @azeós

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that but it depends on your purpose of using lazy loading. In most cases, it is for SEO (i.e. for fast page loading).
If you are lazy loading images only for a fast page speed score then you can add this code to your page.

**Here is a working example:**

An image will be loaded when you scroll inside div.

```html
 <html>
<body>

<div id="mydiv" style="width:500px;height:300px;overflow:scroll;">
<h1>Images are not technically inserted into a web page; images are linked to web pages. The tag creates a holding space for the referenced</h1>
     <div class="photo">
        <img data-src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/648/bs-04-1255720.jpg"/>
      </div>
<h2>Images are not technically inserted into a web page; images are linked to web pages. The tag creates a holding space for the referenced image.Images are not technically inserted into a web page; images are linked to web pages. The tag creates a holding space for the referenced image.</h2>

</div>

<script>
  var sw = 0;
document.getElementById('mydiv').onscroll=function(){
  if(sw==0){
      sw=1;
  const lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  for (let i = 0; i < lazyImages.length; i++) {
         lazyImages[i].src = lazyImages[i].getAttribute('data-src');
   }
  }

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Tip:** use `window.onscroll` to apply effect on whole webpage